# Bitbucket markdown is not displayed correctly

Tags: github, markdown, bitbucket

I have a CHANGELOG.md with the following content:

```
##  Bug Fixes
- `commithash` enable main automatic pipeline  
  - Author: committer
  - Date: 01/08/2024 20:15:08
```

The markdown renders good in github and preview of visual studio code / other tools, the result should be:

[image: correct result]

But instead in bitbucket you get this result:

[image: wrong result]

How come? I tried to make it look correct adding more spaces like this (4 spaces in total):

```
##  Bug Fixes
- `commithash` enable main automatic pipeline
    - Author: committer
    - Date: 01/08/2024 20:15:08
```

and it renders like so in bitbucket (why is it not working with 2 spaces like in github and IDEs? Think there is something wrong with markdown in bitbucket):

[image: closer to the correct result but using more spaces than normal]

Even if I paste the markdown here in StackOverflow (with only 2 spaces) the result is as expected:

### Bug Fixes

- `commithash` enable main automatic pipeline

  - Author: committer
  - Date: 01/08/2024 20:15:08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just appears to be a nuance of the particular Markdown implementation in use at Bitbucket.

From the [official tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/markdowndemo/src/master/#markdown-header-lists)

> Lists can be embedded in lists. List items may consist of multiple paragraphs. Each subsequent paragraph in a list item must be indented by either **4 spaces or one tab**

See also the [Markdown Syntax Guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html#Markdownsyntaxguide-Unorderedlist)

Comment: I see, thank you for the research, now just to vent that really sucks, why would they do that lmao, this makes me have to rewrite the entire template I already tested alot on github and hope for any unfixable errors NOT to come apart from that... it just makes no sense to make the code that works everywhere else to not work on their platform ;(

Comment: [The CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/) specifically mentions that this is a point where implementations diverge and that's why they wrote a spec.  Most implementations have lots of extensions, and GitHub's is no exception.  If you want your Markdown to work everywhere, you've got to write it portably.